AOSP Boot Failure on Device After Firmware Burn with AML Burn Tool | boot bl33 ! Enter exception! Value: 0x02000000 REASON: 0x00000004 LR: 0x010000ec
AOSP Boot Failure on Device After Firmware Burn with AML Burn Tool
Issue Description
I successfully used the AML Burn Tool to burn AOSP firmware to my device. However, upon booting, the device fails to boot properly. After three unsuccessful attempts, the following error message is displayed:
boot bl33 !
Enter exception!
Value: 0x02000000 REASON: 0x00000004 LR: 0x010000ec

What I've Tried
I searched for relevant keywords using the error codes in my binary files, but I couldn't find any concrete solutions:
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/data/s905y4_r_fw/bootloader$ grep -rn "Enter exception!"
Binary file uboot-repo/bl2/bin/sc2/s905c2/blob-bl2e.sto.nocs-jts-ap.bin.signed matches
Binary file uboot-repo/bl2/bin/sc2/s905c2/blob-bl2e.sto.nocs-prod.bin.signed matches

thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/data/s905y4_r_fw/bootloader$ grep -rn "boot bl33 !"
Binary file uboot-repo/bl2/bin/sc2/s905c2/blob-bl2e.sto.nocs-jts-ap.bin.signed matches
Binary file uboot-repo/bl2/bin/sc2/s905c2/blob-bl2e.sto.nocs-prod.bin.signed matches
Binary file uboot-repo/fip/sc2/nocs/stage-3b-stbm-prepare-request/output/stbmRefImg.bin matches

These error messages seem to reside in binary files, and I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I'm unable to identify the exact issue or find relevant solutions online.
Console Logs
Below is the console log output from the device when the boot failure occurs:

S4:BL:25dcde;ID:805600260710142D;FEAT:30F:1FFF0000:B002F:1;POC:FF;RCY:0;OVD:0;DFU:0;eMMC:0;RD-0:0;CHK:0;SCS:0;
 efuse value:72d80700
efuse volate:800
read efus idx:2
get efuse index value:2
 set ee_vol 0.83v
OTP_LIC00 : 0f0300000000ff1f2f000b0000000000
OTP_LIC10 : 008207000001fc000c00001000000300
OTP_LIC20 : ffffffbfffff0700c780000800000000
OTP_LIC30 : 00000002010000008f03000203000000

TE: 97672

BL2 Built : 14:51:17, Apr 24 2022. s4 griscure-review-sc2-bl2-10272020-2-136-g30e83bf - jenkins@walle02-sh

Board ID = 2
Set sys clock to 24Mhz
syspll is 1512Mhz. Locked
Set sys clock to 167Mhz
hifipll is 1800Mhz. Locked
bl2_platform_setup
boot area list:
1STBLOB 00000200        0002a000
BL2E    0002a200        00013000
BL2X    0003d200        00011000
DDRFIP  0004e200        00040000
DEVFIP  0008e200        00300000
s_setup from rom:00010081
dma mode
derive RSPK OK
read PFID OK
DDR_DRIVER_VERSION: AML_A_PHY_V_1_28; Built : 14:51:17, Apr 24 2022. s4 griscure-review-sc2-bl2-10272020-2-136-g30e83bf - jenkins@walle02-sh
Cfg max: 3, cur: 1. ddr id: 255. Force loop cfg
adc_average== 7
dram_type==LPDDR4
config==Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR : LPDDR4 Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR dramfreq=1176 MHz
Set ddr clk to 1176 MHz

package_info_value=403prepare training
gate training finish plat/s4/ddr/ddr_lib.c 5472  ,

check_gate_training!
index   99      sub_index       0       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       1       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       2       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       3       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       4       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       5       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       6       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       7       phase   0
CS0 size: 2048MB
Total size: 2048MB @ 1176MHz
DDR : 2048MB @1176MHz

DATA-W[0x0]:0xaaaaaaaa,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0xaaaaaaaa: t 1 t 3 t 5 t 7 t 9 t 11 t 13 t 15 t 17 t 19 t 21 t 23 t 25 t 27 t 29 t 31
DATA-W[0x0]:0x55555555,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x55555555: 0 t 2 t 4 t 6 t 8 t 10 t 12 t 14 t 16 t 18 t 20 t 22 t 24 t 26 t 28 t 30 t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x1,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x1: 0 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x2,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x2: t 1 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x4,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x4: t t 2 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x8,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x8: t t t 3 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x10,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x10: t t t t 4 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x20,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x20: t t t t t 5 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x40,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x40: t t t t t t 6 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x80,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x80: t t t t t t t 7 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x100,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x100: t t t t t t t t 8 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x200,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x200: t t t t t t t t t 9 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x400,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x400: t t t t t t t t t t 10 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x800,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x800: t t t t t t t t t t t 11 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x1000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x1000: t t t t t t t t t t t t 12 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x2000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x2000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t 13 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x4000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x4000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 14 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x8000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x8000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 15 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x10000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x10000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 16 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x20000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x20000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 17 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x40000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x40000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 18 t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x80000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x80000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 19 t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x100000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x100000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 20 t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x200000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x200000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 21 t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x400000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x400000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 22 t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x800000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x800000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 23 t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x1000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x1000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 24 t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x2000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x2000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 25 t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x4000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x4000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 26 t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x8000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x8000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 27 t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x10000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x10000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 28 t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x20000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x20000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 29 t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x40000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x40000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 30 t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x80000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x80000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 31 cs0 DataBus test failed

ADDR-W[0x4]:0xaaaaaaaa,R:0x0
cs0 AddrBus test failed
Cfg max: 3, cur: 2. ddr id: 255. Force loop cfg
adc_average== 7
dram_type==DDR4
config==Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR : DDR4 Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR dramfreq=1176 MHz
Set ddr clk to 1176 MHz

package_info_value=403prepare training
CS0 size: 2048MB(auto)
Total size: 2048MB @ 1176MHz
DDR : 2048MB @1176MHz
cs0 DataBus test pass
cs0 AddrBus test pass

2d-eye soc_vref 0042 0037 0042 0040 0041 0036 0038 0035 0038 0038 0044 0036 0037 0037 0037 0039 0040 0038 0036 0034 0040 0039 0035 0037 0042 0039 0038 0038 0038 0040 0037 0039 0038 0041 0037 0038 0038 0050 0038 0046 0038 0044 0038 0046 average_value_dec 0038 0810 mv
2d-eye dram_vref average_value_dec 0021 vref_ave_voltage 0883 mv range_0 0883 mv range_1 0703 mv
bdlr_step_size ps=433

INFO: bl2_load_bl2ex start!
INFO: load ...
Load: BL2E From: eMMC - 3.0 src: 00002000, dst: 00fffff0, size: 00011000
sdemmc src: ;
INFO: check ...
SHA CHK OK!
INFO: load ...
Load: BL2X From: eMMC - 3.0 src: 00000000, dst: 007ffff0, size: 00011000
sdemmc src: ;
INFO: check ...
SHA CHK OK!
run into bl2e
info: get valid params from BL2 !
bl2_gd_init
BL2E: do things as vendor specific ...
Hello world, now in BL2E

TE: 552125

BL2E Built : 21:09:44, Apr 21 2022. s4 gd41dde3 - jenkins@walle02-sh


Start to do bl2e platform setup!
boot area list:
1STBLOB 00000200        0002a000
BL2E    0002a200        00013000
BL2X    0003d200        00011000
DDRFIP  0004e200        00040000
DEVFIP  0008e200        00300000
eMMC boot @ 0
sw-hs2 s
tun-w: s=3, sz=4
sw8 s
aml log : BL2E load BL3X.....

TE: 596362
Load FIP HDR from eMMC, src: 0x00000000, des: 0x00300000, size: 0x00008000, part: 0
Load BL3X from eMMC, src: 0x00008000, des: 0x00308000, size: 0x0026c260, part: 0
bl30 payload size: 0x00010260
bl30 memcpy
info: process payload 0  bl3x_toc: 0x00300020  bl3x_data: 0x00308000  rc=147
bl40 payload size: 0x00018470
info: process payload 1  bl3x_toc: 0x00300048  bl3x_data: 0x00319000  rc=187
bl31 payload size: 0x00040470
info: process payload 2  bl3x_toc: 0x00300070  bl3x_data: 0x00332000  rc=218
bl32 payload size: 0x00080470
info: process payload 3  bl3x_toc: 0x00300098  bl3x_data: 0x00373000  rc=260
bl33 memcpy
bl33 payload size: 0x00180260 offset: 0x000f4000
info: process payload 4  bl3x_toc: 0x003000c0  bl3x_data: 0x003f4000  rc=291
info: process payload 5  bl3x_toc: 0x003000e8  bl3x_data: 0x003001e0  rc=147
info: process payload 6  bl3x_toc: 0x00300110  bl3x_data: 0x00300fe0  rc=187
info: process payload 7  bl3x_toc: 0x00300138  bl3x_data: 0x00301de0  rc=218
info: process payload 8  bl3x_toc: 0x00300160  bl3x_data: 0x00302be0  rc=260
info: process payload 9  bl3x_toc: 0x00300188  bl3x_data: 0x003039e0  rc=291
info: process payload 10  bl3x_toc: 0x003001b0  bl3x_data: 0x003047e0  rc=337
aml log : BL2E loading BL3X is done...!
boot bl2x
params to bl2x, address=0x0100c130


 Hello, we are in BL2X world !

TE: 658913

BL2X Built : 14:16:15, Jan 10 2022. s4 gSynamedia_v1.0-3-g61a1ae4 - jenkins@walle02-sh

bl2_platform_setup
INFO: get valid list_blobinfo, 0x0100c130
Info: get valid bl31 payload info, address= 0x00332000 size= 0x00040470
Info: bl31 image is now ready !
Info: get valid bl40 payload info, address= 0x00319000 size= 0x00018470

FEAT_DISABLE_SECURE_ENCLAVE: 1
bl2e_2 entry: 010000c0
run into bl31
NOTICE:  BL31: v1.3(release):0da1128eb
NOTICE:  BL31: Built : 12:15:47, Oct  8 2022
BL31:tsensor calibration: tsensor1 = 8600007e
[mhu]: mhu_init-v1
[mhu]: 0xfe007080, 0x12120210
[mhu]: 0xfe007084, 0x12121002
[mhu]: 0xfe00708c, 0xa0a0802
[mhu]: 0xfe007010, 0x2
[mhu]: 0xfe007018, 0x10
[mhu]: 0xfe007014, 0x8
[mhu]: 0xfe007020, 0x89
[mhu]: 0xfe007024, 0x440
[mhu]: 0xfe007028, 0x6
[mhu]: mhu_init-v1 done
DEVICE_MVN=0x0
NOTICE:  BL31: S4 normal boot!
E/TC:0 00 INFO:    BL3-2: ATOS-V3.8.0-0cd2a2106 (gcc version 8.3.0 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 8.3-2019.03 (arm-rel-8.36))) #1 Tue Apr 19 08:29:21 UTC 2022 arm
E/TC:0 00 INFO:    BL3-2: secure time TEE
E/TC:0 00 INFO:    BL3-2: Chip: S4 Rev: B (37:B - 0:4)
Hello world again, bl2e meet you guys!
valid entry info for bl33, pc = 0x00000000
======== smc start aocpu ========
boot bl33 !
Enter exception!
Value: 0x02000000 REASON: 0x00000004 LR: 0x010000ec
S4:BL:25dcde;ID:805600260710142D;FEAT:30F:1FFF0000:B002F:1;POC:FF;RCY:0;OVD:0;DFU:0;eMMC:0;RD-1:0;CHK:0;SCS:0;
 efuse value:72d80700
efuse volate:800
read efus idx:2
get efuse index value:2
 set ee_vol 0.83v
OTP_LIC00 : 0f0300000000ff1f2f000b0000000000
OTP_LIC10 : 008207000001fc000c00001000000300
OTP_LIC20 : ffffffbfffff0700c780000800000000
OTP_LIC30 : 00000002010000008f03000203000000

TE: 97480

BL2 Built : 14:51:17, Apr 24 2022. s4 griscure-review-sc2-bl2-10272020-2-136-g30e83bf - jenkins@walle02-sh

Board ID = 2
Set sys clock to 24Mhz
syspll is 1512Mhz. Locked
Set sys clock to 167Mhz
hifipll is 1800Mhz. Locked
bl2_platform_setup
boot area list:
1STBLOB 00000200        0002a000
BL2E    0002a200        00013000
BL2X    0003d200        00011000
DDRFIP  0004e200        00040000
DEVFIP  0008e200        00300000
s_setup from rom:00010081
dma mode
derive RSPK OK
read PFID OK
DDR_DRIVER_VERSION: AML_A_PHY_V_1_28; Built : 14:51:17, Apr 24 2022. s4 griscure-review-sc2-bl2-10272020-2-136-g30e83bf - jenkins@walle02-sh
Cfg max: 3, cur: 1. ddr id: 255. Force loop cfg
adc_average== 7
dram_type==LPDDR4
config==Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR : LPDDR4 Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR dramfreq=1176 MHz
Set ddr clk to 1176 MHz

package_info_value=403prepare training
gate training finish plat/s4/ddr/ddr_lib.c 5472  ,

check_gate_training!
index   99      sub_index       0       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       1       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       2       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       3       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       4       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       5       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       6       phase   0
index   99      sub_index       7       phase   0
CS0 size: 2048MB
Total size: 2048MB @ 1176MHz
DDR : 2048MB @1176MHz

DATA-W[0x0]:0xaaaaaaaa,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0xaaaaaaaa: t 1 t 3 t 5 t 7 t 9 t 11 t 13 t 15 t 17 t 19 t 21 t 23 t 25 t 27 t 29 t 31
DATA-W[0x0]:0x55555555,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x55555555: 0 t 2 t 4 t 6 t 8 t 10 t 12 t 14 t 16 t 18 t 20 t 22 t 24 t 26 t 28 t 30 t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x1,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x1: 0 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x2,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x2: t 1 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x4,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x4: t t 2 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x8,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x8: t t t 3 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x10,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x10: t t t t 4 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x20,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x20: t t t t t 5 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x40,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x40: t t t t t t 6 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x80,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x80: t t t t t t t 7 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x100,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x100: t t t t t t t t 8 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x200,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x200: t t t t t t t t t 9 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x400,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x400: t t t t t t t t t t 10 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x800,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x800: t t t t t t t t t t t 11 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x1000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x1000: t t t t t t t t t t t t 12 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x2000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x2000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t 13 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x4000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x4000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 14 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x8000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x8000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 15 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x10000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x10000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 16 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x20000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x20000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 17 t t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x40000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x40000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 18 t t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x80000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x80000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 19 t t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x100000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x100000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 20 t t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x200000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x200000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 21 t t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x400000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x400000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 22 t t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x800000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x800000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 23 t t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x1000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x1000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 24 t t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x2000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x2000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 25 t t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x4000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x4000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 26 t t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x8000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x8000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 27 t t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x10000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x10000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 28 t t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x20000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x20000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 29 t t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x40000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x40000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 30 t
DATA-W[0x0]:0x80000000,R:0x0 data pin check pattern 0x80000000: t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t 31 cs0 DataBus test failed

ADDR-W[0x4]:0xaaaaaaaa,R:0x0
cs0 AddrBus test failed
Cfg max: 3, cur: 2. ddr id: 255. Force loop cfg
adc_average== 7
dram_type==DDR4
config==Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR : DDR4 Rank0_32bit_ch0
DDR dramfreq=1176 MHz
Set ddr clk to 1176 MHz

package_info_value=403prepare training
CS0 size: 2048MB(auto)
Total size: 2048MB @ 1176MHz
DDR : 2048MB @1176MHz
cs0 DataBus test pass
cs0 AddrBus test pass

2d-eye soc_vref 0042 0038 0045 0039 0040 0036 0037 0036 0038 0037 0044 0036 0036 0037 0036 0039 0039 0038 0038 0038 0039 0039 0037 0037 0040 0038 0038 0039 0038 0040 0038 0039 0039 0040 0037 0038 0038 0050 0038 0045 0038 0046 0038 0047 average_value_dec 0038 0810 mv
2d-eye dram_vref average_value_dec 0021 vref_ave_voltage 0883 mv range_0 0883 mv range_1 0703 mv
bdlr_step_size ps=429

INFO: bl2_load_bl2ex start!
INFO: load ...
Load: BL2E From: eMMC - 3.2 src: 00002000, dst: 00fffff0, size: 00011000
sdemmc src: ;
INFO: check ...
SHA CHK OK!
INFO: load ...
Load: BL2X From: eMMC - 3.2 src: 00000000, dst: 007ffff0, size: 00011000
sdemmc src: ;
INFO: check ...
SHA CHK OK!
run into bl2e
info: get valid params from BL2 !
bl2_gd_init
BL2E: do things as vendor specific ...
Hello world, now in BL2E

TE: 553276

BL2E Built : 21:09:44, Apr 21 2022. s4 gd41dde3 - jenkins@walle02-sh


Start to do bl2e platform setup!
boot area list:
1STBLOB 00000200        0002a000
BL2E    0002a200        00013000
BL2X    0003d200        00011000
DDRFIP  0004e200        00040000
DEVFIP  0008e200        00300000
eMMC boot @ 2
sw-hs2 s
tun-w: s=3, sz=4
sw8 s
aml log : BL2E load BL3X.....

TE: 595027
Load FIP HDR from eMMC, src: 0x00000000, des: 0x00300000, size: 0x00008000, part: 2
Load BL3X from eMMC, src: 0x00008000, des: 0x00308000, size: 0x0026c260, part: 2
bl30 payload size: 0x00010260
bl30 memcpy
info: process payload 0  bl3x_toc: 0x00300020  bl3x_data: 0x00308000  rc=147
bl40 payload size: 0x00018470
info: process payload 1  bl3x_toc: 0x00300048  bl3x_data: 0x00319000  rc=187
bl31 payload size: 0x00040470
info: process payload 2  bl3x_toc: 0x00300070  bl3x_data: 0x00332000  rc=218
bl32 payload size: 0x00080470
info: process payload 3  bl3x_toc: 0x00300098  bl3x_data: 0x00373000  rc=260
bl33 memcpy
bl33 payload size: 0x00180260 offset: 0x000f4000
info: process payload 4  bl3x_toc: 0x003000c0  bl3x_data: 0x003f4000  rc=291
info: process payload 5  bl3x_toc: 0x003000e8  bl3x_data: 0x003001e0  rc=147
info: process payload 6  bl3x_toc: 0x00300110  bl3x_data: 0x00300fe0  rc=187
info: process payload 7  bl3x_toc: 0x00300138  bl3x_data: 0x00301de0  rc=218
info: process payload 8  bl3x_toc: 0x00300160  bl3x_data: 0x00302be0  rc=260
info: process payload 9  bl3x_toc: 0x00300188  bl3x_data: 0x003039e0  rc=291
info: process payload 10  bl3x_toc: 0x003001b0  bl3x_data: 0x003047e0  rc=337
aml log : BL2E loading BL3X is done...!
boot bl2x
params to bl2x, address=0x0100c130


 Hello, we are in BL2X world !

TE: 666103

BL2X Built : 14:16:15, Jan 10 2022. s4 gSynamedia_v1.0-3-g61a1ae4 - jenkins@walle02-sh

bl2_platform_setup
INFO: get valid list_blobinfo, 0x0100c130
Info: get valid bl31 payload info, address= 0x00332000 size= 0x00040470
Info: bl31 image is now ready !
Info: get valid bl40 payload info, address= 0x00319000 size= 0x00018470

FEAT_DISABLE_SECURE_ENCLAVE: 1
bl2e_2 entry: 010000c0
run into bl31
NOTICE:  BL31: v1.3(release):0da1128eb
NOTICE:  BL31: Built : 12:15:47, Oct  8 2022
BL31:tsensor calibration: tsensor1 = 8600007e
[mhu]: mhu_init-v1
[mhu]: 0xfe007080, 0x12120210
[mhu]: 0xfe007084, 0x12121002
[mhu]: 0xfe00708c, 0xa0a0802
[mhu]: 0xfe007010, 0x2
[mhu]: 0xfe007018, 0x10
[mhu]: 0xfe007014, 0x8
[mhu]: 0xfe007020, 0x89
[mhu]: 0xfe007024, 0x440
[mhu]: 0xfe007028, 0x6
[mhu]: mhu_init-v1 done
DEVICE_MVN=0x0
NOTICE:  BL31: S4 normal boot!
E/TC:0 00 INFO:    BL3-2: ATOS-V3.8.0-0cd2a2106 (gcc version 8.3.0 (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 8.3-2019.03 (arm-rel-8.36))) #1 Tue Apr 19 08:29:21 UTC 2022 arm
E/TC:0 00 INFO:    BL3-2: secure time TEE
E/TC:0 00 INFO:    BL3-2: Chip: S4 Rev: B (37:B - 0:4)
Hello world again, bl2e meet you guys!
valid entry info for bl33, pc = 0x00000000
======== smc start aocpu ========
boot bl33 !
Enter exception!
Value: 0x02000000 REASON: 0x00000004 LR: 0x010000ec
S4:BL:25dcde;ID:805600260710142D;FEAT:30F:1FFF0000:B002F:1;POC:FF;RCY:0;OVD:0;DFU:0;NAND:81;SPINOR:0;RD-0:0;CHK:1;RD-1:0;CHK:1;SD:2002;USB:ADFU▒S4:BL:25dcde;ID:805600260710142D;FEAT:30F:1FFF0000:B002F:1;POC:FF;RCY:0;OVD:0;DFU:1;USB:0;RD-00:0


Question

What could be causing the boot failure with the above error messages?
How can I further debug or resolve this issue, considering the errors seem to be related to binary files?
Are there any specific tools or techniques for analyzing binary files to trace the root cause of the problem?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.
